# OpenGL ES: Moving images by touching screen

Tags: android, opengl-es

Let's say there are two images (sprites) on the screen rendered by GLSurfaceView. I want to move one of the images by touching and dragging it. I know that it is possible to compare the coordinates of the images and the touch position then act accordingly however, I wonder if there is a better way like attaching listener to the images directly?

Comment: You would have to code it yourself...make all the touchable objects subclass your GL drawable object, and in your rendering loop test all touchable objects and call their listeners as appropriate. Or you can use a library like LibGDX.

Comment: Another "brilliant" question.